# Print numbers where adjacent digits differ by 1

Tags: python

> Problem:To print all the positive numbers less than N in which all adjacent digits differ by 1.

I recently started solving online coding challenges. I have written the below code. Could anyone of you let me know of there is any other optimal solution for this question.?

```
n=int(input('Enter the Number:'))

for i in range(n):

    if (i<11):
        print(i,end=' ')
        continue
    elif(i<100):
        digit1=i%10
        digit2=i//10
        if(abs(digit1-digit2)==1):
            print(i,end=' ')
    elif(i>100 and i<1000):
        temp=i
        digit1=i%10
        temp=temp//10
        digit2=temp%10
        temp=temp//10
        digit3=temp%10
        if(abs(digit1-digit2)==1 and abs(digit2-digit3)==1):
            print(i,end=' ')
```

> Output:

Enter the Number:105

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 21 23 32 34 43 45 54 56 65 67 76 78 87 89 98 101

Comment: your question IMO is not suited for stack overflow it belong to stack Code review. In stack overflow you should not asks question about working code.

Comment: @RomainL. Sure will follow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to loop to `n`. You can generate the numbers directly, using the fact that the smaller numbers are prefixes of the larger ones:

```
from collections import deque

def dif1dig(n):
    yield 0
    agenda = deque(range(1, 10))
    while True:
        num = agenda.popleft()
        if num >= n:
            break
        yield num
        r = num % 10 
        if r > 0:
            agenda.append(10*num + r-1)
        if r < 9:
            agenda.append(10*num + r+1)

>>> print(*dif1dig(105))
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 21 23 32 34 43 45 54 56 65 67 76 78 87 89 98 101
```

A Python >= 3.8 implementation not overfilling the agenda:

```
def dif1dig(n):
    yield 0
    agenda = deque(range(1, 10))
    while agenda:
        yield (num := agenda.popleft())
        if (r := num % 10) > 0 and (next_lo := 10*num + r-1) < n:
            agenda.append(next_lo)
        if r < 9 and (next_hi := 10*num + r+1) < n:
            agenda.append(next_hi)
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this method. Will look into this

Answer (score 0):

You could build this as a recursive generator that adds a digit above or below the previous result's value within the range of N:

```
def oneDiff(N,previous=0):
    if previous >= N: return
    yield previous
    for offset in (-1,1) if previous > 0 else range(1,10):
       number = previous*10 + previous%10 + offset
       if previous and abs(number%10 - previous%10) != 1: continue
       for nextNumber in oneDiff(N,number): yield nextNumber
```

output:

```
print(*oneDiff(105))

0 1 10 101 12 2 21 23 3 32 34 4 43 45 5 54 56 6 65 67 7 76 78 8 87 89 9 98
```

if you need them in order:

```
print(*sorted(oneDiff(105))

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 21 23 32 34 43 45 54 56 65 67 76 78 87 89 98 101
```